# When does a compiled query that returns an IQueryable execute?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

Okay I need a sanity check here...

I've compiled a query that returns an IQueryable when executed.

**On what line(s) should the query actually execute against the database in the following example?**

```
101 IQueryable<T> results = MyCompiledQuery(MyDataContext);
102 List<T> final = (from t in result
103                  where t.ID > 5
104                  select t).ToList<T>();
```

Here is how I define the compiled query

```
 public static Func<MyDataContext, IQueryable<Widget>> MyCompiledQuery=
        CompiledQuery.Compile<MyDataContext, IQueryable<Widget>>(
                      (MyDataContext db) =>
                      from w in db.Widgets
                      where ((w.Type == WidgetType.Atype ||  //Widget.Atype is a Linq to Sql object, that I've defined statically
                              w.Type == WidgetType.Btype ||  //See above comment
                              w.Type == WidgetType.Ctype ) && //See above comment
                              w.Location == WidgetLocation.Domestic)  //Samething applies here
                        select euc);
```

**FOR ADDITIONAL DISCUSSION PLEASE REFER TO:** 
[LINQ to SQL *compiled* queries and when they execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592386/linq-to-sql-compiled-queries-and-when-they-execute/6597160#6597160)

Answer (score 3):

It executes at line 104 (when you call ToList()).

A compiled query is a query that is translated only once to TSQL at compile time, instead of everytime prior to execution.

Comment: You're right, but you are splitting hairs. The ToList is on line 104, not 102. This isn't a trick question, and he wanted to know if compiling the query means that it immediately executes, not whch of the 3 lines is a statement.

Comment: I'd like to think that it executes at 102/104 but it when I run a debugger and SQL Profiler, I see an SQL statement run after 101 executes and then 12 SQL Statements (one for each result on 101) run at 102/104

Comment: @Antilogic: It dpeends on how you've written your compiled query, right? If it can't be deferred, then it will execute immediately.

Comment: @Alan, see the original post I've updated it to contain an example of my compiled query.

Comment: @Antilogic You can see this behavior when executing statements one-by-one in debugger. Run through both statements without breakpoint and see how many SQL statements were issued.

Comment: By the way, I hope you know that compiled query is not composable, so you first get all records into memory and then select those with ID > 5.

Comment: I think this query actually executes on line 101 (even before calling ToList).  

Comment: You can't set a breakpoint at 104 simply because the debugger doesn't support lambdas (and hence LINQ statements)  The call to ToList() actually invokes the query to the database; the fact that you can't set a breakpoint on the same line as the ToList() method is irrelevent.

Comment: @Alex, it should send the comparison along to the database bacause you're using the IQueryable type, not IEnumerable.

Answer (score 3):

This Query executes on line 101.  I verified it by doing a SQL Profiler trace.  I guess this is because it is a compiled query.

The filtering you are doing afterwords > 5 is done in memory.

Comment: -1 Check the trace again. There might be some traffic if information about the database structure is needed, but the actual query is not executed by compiling it. This page for example clearly states that you can provide parameter values after the query is compiled, which would not be possible if the query was also executed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297.aspx

Comment: Calling the compiled query method causes the query to run on the database.  I have checked it multiple times with a simple database.  Of course you can pass parameter values, I am not saying compiling causes it to execute, I am saying calling the compiled query method causes it to execute and **not** the .ToList() method.

Answer (score 2):

"On the line 104, when doing ToList conversion."

Well, this answer is incorrect. We invoke delegate stored in MyCompiledQuery variable on line 101 that returns the result of the compiled query, not the query itself.

Comment: I think this query actually executes on line 101 (even before calling ToList).  

Comment: No. Line 101 creates query. The query is executed when actual data are fetched.

Comment: Not in the case of a compiled query, check through the linq 2 sql provider source code. For a compiled query it hits on line 101. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592386/linq-to-sql-compiled-queries-and-when-they-execute/6597160#6597160

Comment: The question was when will the "query actually execute against the database" not when the delegate is executed.

Comment: @Peter. And this delegate creates AND executes query. Originally I thought that it just creates one. I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is called Deferred Execution.
You can read a good post on it [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/joacim/archive/2009/09/09/run-you-later-understanding-deferred-execution-in-linq.aspx).

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, and how I designed my application. However when the app executes line 101, I see a SQL statement fly by in SQL Profiler, and then another SQL Statement for  every result returned by line 101.

Comment: I can confirm what Antilogic posted.  Query executes on line 101

Comment: @Antilogic: The process of compiling the query may need information about the database structure, but it doesn't fetch any data at that stage. If it did, it would not fetch anything later on when you use the result.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know IQueryable never gets executed it just converts the Linq query to a queryable format so that it gets executed whenever its requested.

In this case I guess the moment its asked to convert to a List it queries the result. And no point in fight about line 102 and 104 as both represents a single line.